# How to extract image from HTML and move in front of heading tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am a bit stumped on this one. I have some html that has an image in it, followed by some text. But I need to rearrange the html so the image comes first - so image, then h3 tag, then the text.

EDIT: The cod below does not actually remove the style attribute. I thought it was working till i looked more closely at the html source. So I need help with stripping the style attribute given

```
<p>
<img alt="" src="../../../../images/PeterDoocy5.jpg" style="width: 608px; height: 316px;" /></p>
```

So far I have managed to use the HAP to strip out the style attributes of the images in the page using:

```
 <Extension()> Public Function RemoveStyleAttributes(input As String)
        Dim cleint As New WebClient

        Dim html As New HtmlDocument
        html.LoadHtml(input)

        Dim elementsWithStyleAttribute = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@img")

        If elementsWithStyleAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each element In elementsWithStyleAttribute
                element.Attributes("style").Remove()
            Next
        End If
        Return input
    End Function
```

But I am at a loss as to how then pull put the image and put in front of the H3 tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="item">
      <div class="content galleryItem">
         <h3>
            DOJ court docs in Abu Khattallah case dispel Obama Admin narrative about the anti-Islam video                            
         </h3>
         <p>
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="../../../../images/AbuKhattala.jpg" />
         </p>
         <p>
            But it was an awful, disgusting video.....
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The Extension method now:

```
   <Extension()> Public Function RemoveStyleAttributes(html As HtmlDocument)


        Dim divs = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content galleryItem']")

        For Each div As HtmlNode In divs
            'get <img> and remove its style attribute'
            Dim img = div.SelectSingleNode("./p/img[@style]")
            img.Attributes("style").Remove()
            'remove <h3> and <p>text here</p>'
            Dim h3 = div.SelectSingleNode("./h3")
            h3.Remove()
            Dim text = div.SelectSingleNode("./p[not(img)]")
            text.Remove()
            'add <h3> and <p>text here</p> to the parent again in desired order'
            div.AppendChild(h3)
            div.AppendChild(text)
        Next


        Return html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.ToString
    End Function
```

Attempting to use it as @Html.Raw(item.PostSummary.RemoveStyleAttributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
<Extension()> Public Function RemoveStyleAttributes(input As String)
    Dim cleint As New WebClient
    Dim html As New HtmlDocument
    html.LoadHtml(input)

    For Each div As HtmlNode In divs
        'get <img> and remove its style attribute'
        Dim img = div.SelectSingleNode("./p/img[@style]")
        img.Attributes("style").Remove()
        'remove <h3> and <p>text here</p>'
        Dim h3 = div.SelectSingleNode("./h3")
        h3.Remove()
        Dim text = div.SelectSingleNode("./p[not(img)]")
        text.Remove()
        'add <h3> and <p>text here</p> to the parent again in desired order'
        div.AppendChild(h3)
        div.AppendChild(text)
    Next
    Return html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.ToString
End Function
```

**Output** (formatted. given input html as posted in this question) **:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="item">
      <div class="content galleryItem">
         <p>
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="../../../../images/AbuKhatta
               la.jpg">
         </p>
         <h3>
            DOJ court docs in Abu Khattallah case dispel Obama Admin narrative a
            bout the anti-Islam video
         </h3>
         <p>
            But it was an awful, disgusting video.....
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it as extension method and get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I my view i tried @Html.Raw(item.PostSummary.RemoveStyleAttributes) but that did not work. What I am missing as far as using as an extension  method?

Comment: Your extension method should've returned `html.DocumentNode.OuterElement`, instead of raw unprocessed `input`...

Comment: If I return html.documentnode.outerhtml it does not appear as an extension method via intellisense. I posted the code in my original answer for the extension method.

Comment: Don't change the function parameter, only change the return value. Check my updated code...

Comment: Okay just tried it again and I still get a Object reference error. This is how i am calling the extension method:  @Html.Raw(item.PostSummary.RemoveStyleAttributes)